# How can I validate a phone number for my location?

Tags: java, android

How can I validate a phone number for my location like most messaging apps do (WhatsApp and Telegram)?. Is there some API for this and if so how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Google libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) it can do some validation. You can try live demo [here](http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Neutrino API](http://www.neutrinoapi.com/api/phone-validate/) for that and many other things.

[And google has it's own too, called `libphonenumber`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google libphonenumber for validation as ma3a mentioned. It is what google uses on Android phones to determine that you are writing a phone number. For a much simpler approach you could use a regex. (Here is a site that has a list of them that might be sufficient: [regexlib.net](http://www.regexlib.net/Search.aspx?k=phone))